# youtube gives sound no video in chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, youtube

Running the latest updates in Ubuntu (16.04). I didn't have a problem before. I'm also using the Nouveau display driver, even though I have an Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia display adapter on my laptop. This because I've experienced heavy screen tearing with the Nvidia drivers, which I don't have with Nouveau.

I've done some research, this problem has been reported on google forums around 2011, which had something to do with the hardware acceleration but the problem has been reported as identified and fixed.

Any idea how I can fix it? I've just been having it since a couple days after updating (apt dist-upgrade).

I'll provide any additional info when asked, not sure what exactly is needed.

This is an intermittent problem. Sometimes it gets resolved by reloading the page, sometimes not. Sometimes it is resolved by closing the browser and re-opening the page. Just clicking on another video never resolves the issue and sometimes it happens from the first video I play.

Videos from other sources never have this problem.
I do have Adblock Plus enabled, as well as uMatrix, but turning them off do not make any difference.

Any fixes, as well as some ideas to troubleshoot this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried disabling the hardware acceleration?

Comment: no, I can't seem to find the switch to turn it off anymore :(

Comment: I did switch from the Nouveau driver to the Nvidia driver though, no difference. Seems more like an issue with Chrome and its flash implementation

Comment: In the settings window, go to the bottom, click advanced, and it should be a checkbox near the bottom.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help, but which settings window are you talking about? All Settings > Display doesn't show an advanced button. All Settings > Appearance doesn't show an advanced button. I checked the nvidia settings and I don't see any hardware acceleration anywhere. I see hardware acceleration for flash is enabled in chrome://gpu, but I can't change it. What am I missing and where is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant the settings in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, for now it seems to have solved the issue. You might want to put that as an answer and I'll rate it as solved.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes a hardware problem which can be solved by disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome.

In the Chrome settings page, scroll to the bottom and click "Advanced Settings" to show more options. Scroll down again near the bottom and uncheck the hardware acceleration option.

You may need to restart the browser for changes to take effect.